# Calling action helper from action helper problem - undefined view variable

Tags: php, zend-framework

So I have an action helper (from which I call a second action helper):

```
<?php
class My_Controller_Action_Helper_Helper1 extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract
{   
    public function direct()
    {
        $theActionController = $this->getActionController();
        $helper =  Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('Helper2');
        $helper->direct(theActionController );
    }
}
```

Here is my second helper, you can see I send a variable to view:

```
<?php
class My_Controller_Action_Helper_Helper2 extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract
{   
    public function direct(theActionController )
    {
        $theActionController->view->a = 'bbb';
    }
}
```

In my controller I do:

```
$this->_helper->helper1();
var_dump($this->view->a);
```

The output is:

```
NULL
```

Why is that?

I send the controller object as an argument to the second helper from the first.

Comment: If you use $theActionController->initView() before set the value it works?

Answer (score 1):

Is it just a typo or are you actually missing the dollar sign prefixes on the two `theActionController` instances?